# How to debug tensorboard code

Tags: debugging, tensorboard

I would like to extend tensorboard with new features. For that I need a debugger for debugging the front-end. I have tried Visual Studio core debugger but it does not find the source-map.

Is it possible to debug the code?
What is the recommended IDE for tensorboard development?